# Deadlock in SELECT FOR UPDATE query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-deadlocks

I have table say

**TAB1**

```
ID, TARGET, STATE, NEXT
```

Column `ID` is the primary key.

The query is that is showing deadlock is similar to this

```
SELECT * 
FROM TAB1 
WHERE NEXT = (SELECT MIN(NEXT) FROM TAB1 WHERE TARGET=? AND STATE=?) FOR UPDATE
```

I did an explain plan I see something like this:

```
| Id  | Operation             | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |               |     1 |  8095 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  FOR UPDATE           |               |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   BUFFER SORT         |               |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL  | TAB1          |     1 |  8095 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     SORT AGGREGATE    |               |     1 |  2083 |            |          |
|*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| TAB1          |     1 |  2083 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
```

Since the query is doing TABLE ACCESS FULL twice, so I'm suspecting 2 session executing the same query will access the rows in different orders.

Can indexing of columns will help in preventing the deadlock? Say creating an index on NEXT??? Or by changing the PRIMARY to NON CLUSTERED KEY?? Note: Normally, the table will have max 1000 rows.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: you can have deadlock here and indexes will not help, give us more information - what are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi llya, My queries tries to find the minimum next and then update that row. Its a scheduler application that tries to find a task with minimum next to execute it. What can be done to avoid deadlock? I'm

Comment: I'm assuming you have no indexes. Would suggest one on TARGET/STATE and possibly NEXT (that's _one_ index) and a separate index on NEXT. But, there are more efficient ways of doing this without scanning the table a second time. [For instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435503/subquery-getting-the-highest-score/19435681#19435681). _Nothing_ will stop locks as you're locking the table. The only solution is to either not lock the table or for your other queries to use `nowait` so they ignore locked rows.

Comment: @ Ben, I have no index except for the ID (task ID is primary key). I did not understand how to avoid table scan second time (i.e. subquery). Does the subquery (i.e.SELECT MIN(NEXT) FROM TAB1 WHERE TARGET=? AND STATE=?) locks the table? My opinion no.

Comment: No, the SELECT FOR UPDATE that's not in your posted query but is in the explain plan locks the table @Danny. Look at the link, change the query to `select * from ( select a.*, min(next) over ( partition by target, state) as mn from tab1 a) where mn = min_next` and add an index on `target, state, next` (it's only 1,000 rows so should be tiny). This is not going to stop locking though. You're locking the table so investigate nowait and see if it does what you want.

Comment: Ok..let me try it out. Thanks

Comment: There is no need to guess about which queries are causing a deadlock.  Every deadlock will generate a trace file, that trace file will tell you exactly what statements caused the issue.  If you know the exact time one of the deadlocks occurred ask a DBA to look for a trace file generated at that time.

Comment: Deadlock trace shows the above query being the reason for deadlock "SELECT * FROM TAB1 WHERE NEXT = (SELECT MIN(NEXT) FROM TAB1 WHERE TARGET=? AND STATE=?) FOR UPDATE".   The 2 sessions                     ---------Blocker(s)--------  ---------Waiter(s)---------
Resource Name          process session holds waits  process session holds waits
TX-00090010-00a2b376        24     288     X             46      68           X
TX-00020008-00a89759        46      68     X             24     288           X

Comment: Please show the **whole** transaction --> all commands performed by the transaction until commit. Trace shows `SELECT * ... FOR UPDATE`, but this is not necessarily a main reason of the deadlock.

Comment: @DannyZen If that statement is listed in *both* sessions (it takes two statements to deadlock), and those are the only statements locking the relevant rows, then most likely the query has multiple execution plans.  For example, a full table scan and an index scan can access the same rows in a different order, causing a deadlock.  If that is the case, you may need to ensure plan stability regardless of the bind variables.  Just to test out the theory, you may want to try a hint, like `/*+ full(tab1) */`.

Answer (score -2):

Addind a non clustered index on the NEXT column would indeed boost your performance and reduce your deadlock issues.

Comment: reduce, but not eliminate, I suppose it is mysql, so if there are several rows in table with same NEXT value, this query will produce deadlocks sometimes

Comment: You suspect incorrectly @IlyaBursov, this is Oracle and has been tagged Oracle and SQL Server and not MySQL.

Comment: Why would adding an index to the NEXT column help at all? You still need to evaluate the predicates.

Comment: Do I need to index TARGET and STATE column? I think MIN() is doing a FULL SCAN and then the WHERE clause also doing as there is no primary key in the WHERE clause. The NEXT value is System.currentTimeMillis(). So, rows with same NEXT is mimimal.

Comment: @Ben, the principal query predicates uses the next column. That's why it should do something.

Comment: @ Jonysuise, I have to select the minimum NEXT. not ID.

Comment: @Jonysuise, ah, sorry being very stupid there. It doesn't stop the other full-scan though.

Comment: I would add an index on the next column, his cardinality is very high and the rows locked for update are those from the principal query, not the subquery.

Comment: So @Jonysuis, So you mean the subquery (SELECT MIN(NEXT) FROM TAB1 WHERE TARGET=? AND STATE=?) doesnot lock the rows?

Comment: No cursor. Its a prepared statement.